# Eigenvalues of the complement graph of a k-regular graph

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I didn't see this asked anywhere else, and I'm really struggling with understanding and solving this question:

> Let $G$ be a simple k-regular graph.
>
> Show that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of *G* distinct from $k$, then $-1-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $G^C$ with the same multiplicity.

What I know:

Since $G$ is k-regular, it has an eigenvalue of $k$ and corresponding eigenvector 1. Deduced from this is that $G^C$ has eigenvalue $n-k-1$ with corresponding eigenvector 1. I also know that eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are orthogonal, but I'm not sure if this is helpful.

Thanks in advance. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Maybe something like this should hold? $Gx = \lambda x \implies G^c(1-x) = (-1-\lambda) x$

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thank you!